# Removing the arms/legs from a mixamo model

Tags: modeling, armature, bones, workflow

I'm quite new to blender so I don't know how tricky this may or may not be.

I'm trying to specifically remove the arms/legs from a Mixamo model. I've tried going into edit mode and deleting vertices, but I thought that would be too tedious given that they are all together.

I also tried moving the pose to a different position before going into edit mode, but the pose gets reset in edit mode as well. Any tips/hints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially get rid of the arms by adding a cube, scaling the cube over the part of the model that you don't want, and adding a boolean modifier to that cube. In the boolean settings, make sure that the boolean operation is set to difference. (It should be the default). Finally, set the object that it removes mesh from to your model. Now apply the modifier.